Increasing limit integral of measures

Let ($X$, $\Sigma$) be a measurable space, $(\mu_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of measures such that for every $E$ in $\Sigma$ the sequence $(\mu_{n}(E))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is nondecreasing and $\nu$ the measure given by
$$
\nu(E)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{n}(E)
$$


Let $(E_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\Sigma$ be such that is an increasing sequence and $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_{n}=X$ and assume that for any $E \in \Sigma$ it holds that
$$
\mu_{n+1}(E \cap E_{n})=\mu_{n}(E)
$$
Show that if $f$ is integrable respect to $\nu$ and measurable, and there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ vanishes outside $E_{N}$, then
$$
\int f d\nu= \int f d\mu_{N}
$$

I know that if $f$ is integrable with respect to $\nu$ and measurable we have that $$
\int f d\nu= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f d\mu_{n}
$$




Could you help me solve this problem ?. I really don't know how to attack it, I've tried for a long time and I can't do it.


If $f=0$ for $X\setminus E_N$, it follows that $\int f d\nu=\int_{E_N}f d\nu$, and this equality holds when integrating with respect every other measure, keep that in mind. If $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing, verify that for every $n\geq N$ we have $\mu_n(E_N)=\mu_N(E_N)$, which immediately implies that $\int_{E_N}f d\mu_n=\int_{E_N}f d\mu_N$. Note that the precondition is sufficient for taking limits as $n\to\infty$.
